# Django Inheritance project

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-errors

Sir/Madam, I'm trying here to inherit a project in Django. I wrote here 1 single CommonData and 3 children classes. Trying to inherit 2 common data fields 'name' and 'location'. I code in the admin.py file also. I think everything I wrote is correct. But, I got the following error while making migrations.
I don't know where I done a mistake? please give me a hint to fix it. Thank you.

```
 ERRORS:
    <class 'abapp.admin.CustomerAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[0]' refers to 'name', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'CustomerAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'abapp.Customer'.
    <class 'abapp.admin.CustomerAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[1]' refers to 'location', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'CustomerAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'abapp.Customer'.
    <class 'abapp.admin.EmployeeAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[0]' refers to 'name', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'EmployeeAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'abapp.Employee'.
    <class 'abapp.admin.EmployeeAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[1]' refers to 'location', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'EmployeeAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'abapp.Employee'.
    <class 'abapp.admin.StudentAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[0]' refers to 'name', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'StudentAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'abapp.Student'.
    <class 'abapp.admin.StudentAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[1]' refers to 'location', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'StudentAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'abapp.Student'.
```

models.py file

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class CommonData(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Student(models.Model):
    # name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    # location = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    marks = models.IntegerField()
    clg_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Employee(models.Model):
    # name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    # location = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    salary = models.IntegerField()
    company = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Customer(models.Model):
    # name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    # location = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    sales = models.IntegerField()
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
```

Comment: It is clear that `name` is not an attribute of any active model, there is no inheritance seen in the models `Student`, `Employee`, `Customer` from `CommonData`.

Comment: Sir, I didn't understand what you said. I am new to Django. Will you please explain that where I done the mistake? Why that error came sir?

Comment: if answer works, please, consider mark it

Answer (score 1):

You should be fixing inheritance in the active models from `CommonData` abstract model. Checkout the corrections made in defining `Student`, `Employee`, `Customer` model classes. After changing, it should be working most likely.

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class CommonData(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Student(CommonData):
    marks = models.IntegerField()
    clg_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Employee(CommonData):
    salary = models.IntegerField()
    company = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Customer(CommonData):
    sales = models.IntegerField()
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @Anvesh sir. Error fixed.

Comment: You could upvote the solution, if it is helpful in resolving your issue.